# Apple rejected due to crash. Can not reproduce, with sha256

Tags: ios, xcode

I have tested my app on all the iOS devices I have been able to get my hands on, and on the emulators connected to XCode without any problems. Now I got word back from Apple that the app is rejected due to a crash on iPad 3rd Gen running iOS 6.0.1.

From the crash log I can read:

```
0   libsystem_c.dylib               0x39421d74 strlen + 28
1   Appname                         0x0000da16 +[Utilities sha256:] (Utilities.m:28)
2   Appname                         0x0000dc1c +[Utilities complete256Hash:]             (Utilities.m:46)
3   Appname                         0x0000ea66 -[SettingController TestSettingsTapped] (SettingController.m:83)
```

The problem seems to originate in the following function, can someone point me to what might be wrong, cause I am not able to reproduce the crash which Apple is getting, so it might be somthing to do with all tested devices being set up for danish.

```
+(NSString*) sha256:(NSString *)clear{
    const char *s=[clear cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSData *keyData=[NSData dataWithBytes:s length:strlen(s)];
    uint8_t digest[CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH]={0};
    CC_SHA256(keyData.bytes, keyData.length, digest);
    NSData *out=[NSData dataWithBytes:digest length:CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    NSString *hash=[out description];
    hash = [hash stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
    hash = [hash stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<" withString:@""];
    hash = [hash stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@">" withString:@""];
    return hash; 
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The `strlen()` call you're making on the third line of your snippet is getting passed a bad pointer. The most likely reason for this I can think of is because `s` is nil, because `clear` is also nil.

Comment: I was able to read that the strlen() seemed to be the problem aswell. Yet I can not figure out how Apple have managed to get the value passed to the function to be nil. Would have been nice if they would have supplied what input they have used. I have a test in the function where the fault originates, which says if([InputField.text isEqualToString:@""]) and the fault comes in the else clause, so it should never be able to be empty the value passed.

Comment: On top of that I only call the method I posted from a secondary functions which looks like this: +(NSString*) complete256Hash:(NSString *)cStr{
    NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *SHA1Para = [prefs stringForKey:@"SpecialKey1"];
    NSString *SHA2Para = [prefs stringForKey:@"SpecialKey2"];
    
    NSString *hash = [cStr stringByAppendingString:SHA1Para];
    hash = [Utilities sha256:hash];
    hash = [hash stringByAppendingString:SHA2Para];
    hash = [Utilities sha256:hash];    
    return hash;
}

Comment: If you launch your app for the first time on a device, your userDefaults doesn't exist yet and stringForKey: returns nil so you call sha256 with nil parameter. You need to exit your sha256 method if nil is passed.

Comment: @Johnmph I believe it can be `nil` only if `cStr` is `nil`. I would definitely recommend to add unit tests and test the behavior with different input data, including `nil`.

Comment: Before the user can get to input data which will trigger a call to this method I set the userDefaults.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the nil clear that you are looking for comes from one memory warning (that apple reviewers actively produce to observe your app's behavior).

Comment: If I understand you correctly Apple produce their own memory warning? I have not made a check for nil, cause it is not possible normally for the variable to be nil, since ealier in the code I check that the string value is not empty. So how many places do I need to make a check for nil then? In most of the code I have seen on the web for iOS there is not constant nil checks, should I add that?

Comment: I've missed to ask you if you are using ARC or not, if not, then it may be the memory warning issue.

Comment: The memory warnings have a few levels and they provoque the system to clean his memory, so some data, like views or properties, must be initialized again, so if you loaded some resources and then a random memory warning you'll have some nils. 
The emulator has an option that simulates a moemory warning of wahatever level you want, make some tests with it and you'll discard (or not) the problem :)

Comment: I do use ARC. I save the content of a UITextField to NSUserDefaults and then right after grab the value. This is the one passed to the Sha256 method in the situation where Apple has made my app crash. Can the NSUserDefaults also be cleared?

Comment: I dont think so, but maybe there's some case that you load a nil string from the NSUserDefaults